# Will Google Play Game Services allow turn-based gameplay?

Tags: android, networking, google-play

Will the Google Play Game Services multiplayer allow (turn-by-turn) gameplay like DrawSomething?

Comment: I think it allows anything since the game interfaces with the computer rather then google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is speculation about a future that now has arrived (and in which the answer is clearly "yes").

Answer (score 1):

You are not talking about asynchronous gameplay (which is explained [here](http://nintendo.about.com/od/faqs/g/Asynchronous-Gameplay.htm)).

You are talking about turn-based gameplay. But I think you can relinquish the idea of using Google Game Services, because of the missing realtime gameplay (= you don't need to establish a connection between the clients).

I would recommend using a database, which contains everything relating to the game like the gamestate, the players, who did the last turn and things like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do synchronous gameplay (i.e. playing together in realtime) you can always do asynchronous gameplay as well. The only deciding factor is whether you're able to establish the required connection at any time.

Comment: I fear it may not be that easy since it looks like as if player interaction is necessary (accepting invites, actively creating new games and searching for other players). The API really does seem to be designed in a way that only allows direct peer to peer socket connections over the duration of a real time game session. Maybe the API can be bent in a way to maintain a session that outlives the duration of a so-called "Room". Would be nice to see some actual code samples for that.

Comment: Well, really depends on what you consider "turn by turn". If the other player isn't necessarily online at that moment you'll probably need some kind of server anyway. Don't think Google would allow you to save your game state somehow to some kind of cloud.

Comment: I was thinking about turn-based in a sense of "Ruzzle". You can take your time for making your move. But I see your point and I also understand why Google implemented it that way. It saves resources. Your original answer made me think it could be possible to use the current API in an "asynchronous turn-by-turn" way. I'll experiment with it in the near future and report back.

Comment: Ah yeah, so you mean more similar to "play by (e)mail"? That case you'd probably have to use your own custom server and service or networking stuff.